# printf work-alike wrapper for prefixing and redirecting error messages

Tags: quoting, printf, shellcheck

I have an `error` function in my POSIX `sh` shell code.  It essentially looks like

```
error () {
    printf 'utility: ERROR: ' >&2
    printf "$@" >&2
}
```

The second `printf` makes it so that I can call the function using e.g.

```
error 'Something relating to "%s" went wrong!\n' "$thing"
exit 1
```

and the function would prefix the message with the string `utility: ERROR:` and arrange with everything being sent to standard error while I'm still able to use a formatting string as I would do with `printf`.

Obviously, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) complains about the second `printf`, saying

> SC2059: Don't use variables in the printf format string. Use printf "..%s.." "$foo"

Is it "safe" to do what I do and just ignore this warning (maybe even *disabling* it with a `# shellcheck disable=SC2059` comment in the code)?  Note, I always use my `error` function *exactly* the way I would otherwise use `printf`, i.e. with a static single-quoted first argument.

"Is it safe?" here means "Does my function act as a work-alike wrapper (apart from the redirection) around `printf` in an appropriate way?"

Comment: shellcheck can't tell what you might pass in; what about `error "$(printf 'Something relating to %s went wrong' "$thing")"` -- with some careful quoting inside. Then `error()` just has one parameter that could be printed with `printf "%s\n" "$1"`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks. I'd rather avoid having to construct the string in a command substitution before calling the function. The idea with the function is twofold: 1) do error output in a single location in the code (the function) and 2) make it convenient to call it by making it work just like `printf`.

Comment: `printf -v "$@" >&2`?

Comment: You could construct the argument string *inside* the function, maybe? `printf 'utility: ERROR:%s\n' "$(printf ' %s' "$@")"`

Comment: @αғsнιη POSIX `printf` does not have `-v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe in that you do intend here for the format to be passed as argument. But you have to remember when using the function that it is the format. So maybe you should name your function `errorf` as a reminder.

If you used it as:

```
error "invalid arg: $arg"
```

You'd cause problems like for values of `$arg` like `%99999999s`

Ideally, you'd want to tell shellcheck to ignore that usage of `printf` *and* for it to flag usages of your `printf` where the first argument contains variables.

A couple of notes:

- since you're invoking `printf` twice, that will be at least 2 `write()` system calls. Unlikely  to make any difference whatsoever, and note that some `printf` implementations like `bash`'s will do several system calls under some circumstance as well. The kind of *problem* I'm thinking of is the two parts of the error message being intertwined with the output of another command running in parallel.
- In `error "%s\n" error1 error2` the prefix will be output only for the first error. That's fine if that's how you want to do it. You could also do:

  ```
  errorf() { printf "utility: ERROR: $@" >&2; }
  ```

  for the prefix to be prepended to the format, so it be output every time the format is reused (which would also address the multiple `write()` *issue*).

  That would however not work if you wanted `utility` to be a variable though.

  ```
  PROG_NAME=${0##*/}
  errorf() { printf >&2 "$PROG_NAME: ERROR: $@"; }
  ```

   wouldn't be OK as it would fail when `$0` contains `%` or `\`.

  and 

  ```
  PROG_NAME=${0##*/}
  errorf() {
  format=$1; shift
  printf >&2 "%s: ERROR: $format" "$PROG_NAME" "$@"
  }
  ```

   wouldn't work in the cases where the format is reused (and would mean the user would need to offset by one the `%<n>$d` directives (not that I would recommend using those as they are not portable)).

  I can't think of any easy work around other than escaping the `\` and `%` by hand in the `$PROG_NAME` and even that is not easy as with many `printf` implementations, you'd also need to escape the `0x5c` bytes found in other characters than `\` (for those charsets like BIG5 or GB18030 that have some).

Comment: Much appreciated! And thanks! Yes, renaming the function may be a good thing to do, and I might adopt your suggested single-`printf` suggestion too. Then I'll disable the warning from ShellCheck with a comment (for that specific line).

Comment: I see your edits, and I will have to take that into account later. Thanks!

Comment: If I have a variable utility name in my prefix string, it will most likely be inserted by a `configure` script, which means it won't actually be variable from the script's POV.